# Hibernate: inserting after deleting in an ordered list

Tags: java, hibernate, collections

I've got the following mapping for a list of books (inside a user) + usual getter/setter:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinColumn(name = "book_id", nullable = false)
@IndexColumn(name = "order", nullable = false)
private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
```

and now I'm doing this for a user with two books:

```
User user = getUser(...);
user.getBooks().remove(1); //Remove the last one
user.getBooks().add(new Book("New one!"));
update(user); // ends up calling session.merge()
```

however, although the new book gets persisted, the other one is not removed. Here's the database before/after:

```
  id  | book_id | title  | order
------+---------+--------+-------
   20 |       1 | Book 1 |    0
   21 |       1 | Book 2 |    1

  id  | book_id | title    | order
------+---------+----------+-------
   20 |       1 | Book 1   |    0
   21 |       1 | Book 2   |    1
   22 |       1 | New one! |    1
```

As you can see, the index column gets a duplicate.

This only happens when using ordered/indexed collections. If I remove the `@IndexColumn` annotation, the snippet works as expected. However I need to keep the insertion order. I'm using Hibernate 3.5.6.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**: if instead of the second element, I remove the first one, it gets properly managed.

**2nd UPDATE**: it seems that changing the DAO layer to use "saveOrUpdate" instead of "merge" makes this thing work correctly. It's not a solution, though, as changing that might break existing legacy code.

Comment: IndexColumn is deprecated.. prefer standard JPA OrderColumn annotation..

Comment: I've already tried, but the behavior is the same if I switch to OrderColumn.

Answer (score 1):

Just removing an element from a collection does only work on your database in combination with `orphanRemoval` - when you want to do this explicitly, remove the book using e.g. your entity manager:

```
Book book = user.getBooks().get(1);
entityManager.remove(book);
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid removing the element explicitly, so I tried `orphanRemoval` but it isn't helping: the element is still there too. What could be wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Cascading all persistent events does not includes orphans, so you can use `orphanRemoval=true` if using JPA 2 or `CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN`.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried `orphanRemoval` and now I also gave `@Cascade` with `DELETE_ORPHAN` a try, but there's no difference, the element is not deleted.

Comment: Are there any other references to that book?

Comment: It's the book who keeps the reference to the user (`book_id` joincolumn) so that book should be nowhere but in this user's list.

Comment: I am sorry, but then I can't help you. It is quite strange to me what is happening to you in edit and edit2, maybe there is a bug?

Comment: It may be a bug, or maybe there's something wrong elsewhere, as those reverse-owner mappings are not that common. Thanks!